# Properties of perfect rings

Tags: ring-theory, modules

$\def\rad{\mathrm{rad}~}$
I'm working with perfect rings at the moment and have come up with some questions.

Let $R$ be a perfect ring. Is it true that for all $R$-modules $M$, we have that $M / \rad{M}$ is semi-simple? I think I should be using the fact that $R/\rad{R}$ is semisimple and that $M \cdot \rad{R} = \rad{M}$, but I only get that it is a semisimple $R/\rad{R}$-module.

Also, are there only finitely many simple (left) $R$-modules (up to isomorphism)? I would start from the decomposition of the unit in $R$ into orthogonal idempotents, $1 = e_1 + \dots + e_n$. Hence, if $r e_i \in R e_i$, we should have that $s(r e_i) \in R e_i$, and it also yields all of $R e_i$, since we have inverses in $R$. Is is this easy to show that the $R e_i$ are simple? 
To show that we get all simples this way, I think an argument using the fact that for $y \in S$ where $S$ is not of the form $R e_i$ would yield that $y \cdot 1 = 0$, should work, so there can't be such a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I only get that it is a semisimple $R/rad R$-module.

Well, the simple $R$ modules are precisely the simple $R/rad(R)$ modules, and thus the semisimple $R/rad(R)$ modules are the semisimple $R$ modules, so there you go.

> Also, are there only finitely many simple (left) $R$-modules (up to isomorphism)?

Yes. Again, as above, the simple $R$ modules correspond to simple $R/rad(R)$ modules, and since $R/rad(R)$ is semisimple Artinian (because it is right perfect), it has only as many isotypes of simple right $R$ modules as there are simple components in the Wedderburn decomposition of $R/rad(R)$.